# How many Swipes are too much in Arena?

Tags: hearthstone

I'm currently drafting a Druid deck in the Arena and I'm getting an absolutely huge number of Swipes offered. I have four of them already in my deck, and I just got a fifth offered at round 22 of the drafting.

In the guides on Arena drafting I found Swipe is usually mentioned as an "always pick", but I would assume that there is a point where I should stop picking Swipe and pick something else. How many Swipes are still a good idea, and when should I stop picking Swipe?

Comment: No matter if you add more Swipes please comeback here and comment on your number of wins for this Arena run.

Comment: @ahsteele I've decided to leave it at four Swipes, I could have chosen six if I had wanted to. Let's see how far this deck will take me

Comment: do you have any synergy with that card?  like +spell damage or draw cards with spell?  I suspect the more you get the better since swipe is one of the few druid spells that can damage the enemy hero.

Comment: @z- I don't have any +spell damage cards. If I had a lot of them I would have likely picked every Swipe I could get.

Comment: [This spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0AifXEOqTcGcLdFVvWk1GRjVJTHJUaTVLcGViR1RRTFE&gid=7) seems to suggest no limit to swipe.  I'd probably agree with that unless you have like 20 spells already and only 10 creatures :P

Answer (score 9):

Spells should always be favored over minions when constructing arena decks. Especially if the are really good and cost effective damaging spells like swipe.

Swipe means 4 guaranteed damage to any one, for only 4 cost
+ you get to deal 1 damage to everyone else
+ it has great synergy with spell damage

How many are too much? 
You cannot use swipe the first 3 turns and if you have alot of swipes and not enough draw cards, you will run out of cards fast. That is the most common reasons for losing in the arena.

For a balanced deck your arena should have about 
5/30 draw cards at least
10/30 normal minions at least
5/30 other spells

So you can have about 10 swipes and still have a healthy balanced deck

**Edit:**
Cost effective usually means several things: You spend less mana to take out a higher mana card and/or you are able to do a 1 card for 2(or more) swap. Swipe can accomplish both in the right situations And the fact that you can use it against heroes makes it a good finisher in a pinch. z-

Comment: I disagree with that first blanket statement.  There are a lot of bad spells you should never pick, like moonfire

Comment: Esq can you please clarify what makes a spell "cost effective"?

Comment: @SimonL cost effective usually means several things: You spend less mana to take out a higher mana card and/or you are able to do a 1 card for 2(or more) swap.  Swipe can accomplish both in the right situations And the fact that you can use it against heroes makes it a good finisher in a pinch.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification Esq - you should put that description into your answer!

Comment: @z there are also alot of bad minions. but if you are getting the same level of card minion vs spell, spell is usually the better choice

Comment: If you get the right supporting cards, 15-20 Swipes could be ideal.  - - example - - 1x Bloodmage Thalnos, 4x Kobold Geomancer, 2x Dalaran Mage, 2x Azure Drake, 1x malygos (10 spell dmg minions with 4 draw)... 2x Innervate, 1x Healing Touch, 2x Nourish, 15x Swipe.  Gosh that would be fun!

Answer (score 0):

I've been studying this, and Druid decks with 12 wins posted online with screenshot proof often have 4 even 5 swipes.  I would conclude from this that unless your 4 slot was too full before you started seeing the swipes then 4-5 is still good.  Fireball would be similar, but most cards would not be.  Swipe and Fireball do enough to finish a game if set to the face or address a scary board at a reasonable mana cost.  Most cards can't do both (see flamestrike/lightning storm or pyroblst)